# print two images on single page c#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I want to print two images on single page.
I have tried below code, but it is printing all images on different pages.

```
 public void PD_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        float W = e.MarginBounds.Width;

        float H = e.MarginBounds.Height;

        for (; FileCounter >= 0; FileCounter--)
        {

            try
            {

                Bitmap Bmp = new Bitmap(BmpFiles[FileCounter]);

                if (Bmp.Width / W < Bmp.Height / H)

                    W = Bmp.Width * H / Bmp.Height;

                else
                    H = Bmp.Height * W / Bmp.Width;

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Bmp, 0, 0, W, H);

                break;

            }

            catch
            {

            }

        }

        FileCounter -= 1;

        if (FileCounter > 0)
        {

            e.HasMorePages = true;

        }

        else
        {

            FileCounter = BmpFiles.Length - 1;

        }

    }
```

this will print all images in different page

I want some functionality that will print one image ,leave some space and again prine other image in same page if space is remaining.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're printig just one image per page because you leave the loop with the break-statement at the end of `try`. Instead of using break without a condition you should leave the loop dynamically based on the decision if it is possible to print only one image (not nough space for second image) ore two images (you achieved what you wanted).

```
    //for-loop for printing maximum two images as long as there are files to print
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 && FileCounter >= 0; i++)
    {

        //here comes your printing code just indicated with the draw-call

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Bmp, 0, 0, W, H);

        //after a image was printed decrement your filecounter
        FileCounter --;

        //after a image was drawn check if there is enough space for the next image
        //if there is not enough space leave the loop with break
        if(condition)
             break;
    }
```

At the moment I don't have enough reputation for commenting something on this page... so: never use 'goto' as "Sayka" proposes in his answer. That is really bad style & coding

Comment: How can i check if there is enough space for the next image

Comment: You have a PageBounds property in the EventArguments. These represent the total area of the page. You also know the heigth of your image. Everything else is just mathemathics.  
Remember that 0;0 is in the upper left corner! Use the heigth (or y) of the Property and subtract the heigth of your image with some offset to have space between the images. Then check if the heigth of the remaining area is big enough for your image. Also you maybe should leave some space on the borders of the page.

Comment: Usually creating of printing methods results in trying out if all fits as wished. This is not nice, but the only way to get things placed right. Using a pdf-printer (like freepdf) helps on this ;)

Answer (score 0):

The working of printDocument is like this:
First the program reaches the printPage function, reads all the code and at the end of the function, if there exists a line e.hasMorePages = true; , then the program re-enters the function from the begining and read again the codes to print it to the next page and continues until it reads a line e.hasMorepages = false .. So u dont have to put a loop inside the function. What you have to do is to make variables inside the class, and incre or decrement the variables to make a condition that satisfies e.hasMorePages = false after your printing job has finished..

```
public void PD_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{

    float W = e.MarginBounds.Width;

    // if you are calculating the whole page margin, then split it to carry 2 images

    float H = e.MarginBounds.Height / 2;

    // for space btwn images

    H -= 5.0;

    // First Image
        try
        {

            Bitmap Bmp = new Bitmap(BmpFiles[FileCounter]);

            if (Bmp.Width / W < Bmp.Height / H)

                W = Bmp.Width * H / Bmp.Height;

            else
                H = Bmp.Height * W / Bmp.Width;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Bmp, 0, 0, W, H);

            break;

        }

        catch
        {

        }

      FileCounter --;
      if (FileCounter < 0) goto goDaddy;

     //Second Img
        try
        {

            Bitmap Bmp = new Bitmap(BmpFiles[FileCounter]);

            if (Bmp.Width / W < Bmp.Height / H)

                W = Bmp.Width * H / Bmp.Height;

            else
                H = Bmp.Height * W / Bmp.Width;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Bmp, 0, H + 2.5, W, H);

            break;

        }

        catch
        {

        }        

    FileCounter --;

 goDaddy:;
    e.HasMorePages  = (FileCounter >= 0)


}
```

I haven't checked the code but just tryin to show you the concept..

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work extremely well, doesn't lose any image quality I experienced using memory streams.

```
 private void printBothGraphs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintPreviewDialog custom = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        custom.ClientSize = new Size(1000, 750);

        System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pd = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();


        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Color = true;

        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPageBoth);

        custom.Document = pd;


        custom.ShowDialog();
    }
    private void pd_PrintPageBoth(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        // Create and initialize print font 
        System.Drawing.Font printFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10);
        ev.PageSettings.Color = true;
        // Create Rectangle structure, used to set the position of the chart Rectangle 
        Rectangle myRec = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(ev.MarginBounds.X, ev.MarginBounds.Y, ev.MarginBounds.Width, ev.MarginBounds.Height / 2);
        Rectangle myRec2 = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(ev.MarginBounds.X, ev.MarginBounds.Height / 2 + 90, ev.MarginBounds.Width, ev.MarginBounds.Height / 2);
        //dataChart and outputGraph are two mscharts in my form
        dataChart.Printing.PrintPaint(ev.Graphics, myRec);
        outputGraph.Printing.PrintPaint(ev.Graphics, myRec2);
    }
```